# Turn a list into variables in python

Tags: python, list, csv

I am trying to read a csv file and do some searching in it.

I want to find a way of using the Header in the CSV file as a variable.  Is that possible?

```
with open("Server.csv", newline='', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f :
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    Header = next(reader)

    # This part below is to get the Header on the file.            
    Header_array = []   
    for n in range(len(Header)):
        header_list = Header[n].replace(" ", "_")
        Header_array.append(header_list)
        print(Header_array) # this give me a list
```

The variables I want to extract are

`Application_Name, Environment, server_hostname, OverallStatus, Migration_Date`

How can I use this Header like dynamic variables based on the code below? Let's say if I add "Time" in the csv file tomorrow, I don't need to care about adding Time  = row[x:x][x] below.

```
    for row in reader :
        Application_Name            = row[0:1][0]
        Environment                 = row[1:2][0]
        server_hostname         = row[2:3][0]
        OverallStatus          = row[3:4][0]
        Migration_Date              = row[4:5][0]



        return Application_Name, server_hostname
```

Comment: You want csvDictReader.  Look here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

Comment: Thanks James, you right that's what I am looking for.